# Amazon Athena - Cannot convert variable character to date

Tags: type-conversion, number-formatting, amazon-athena, date-formatting, date-conversion

Using Amazon Athena, I am working with a set of data stored as variable characters and would like to convert them to dates. There are two columns within a table that have dates: (1) action_date and (2) pricing_date.

With action_date, I have been able to successfully convert the original data using the dateparse function with the following query:

```
SELECT  date_parse(s.action_date,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS dataconverted
FROM "database"."sales" s
```

With pricing_date, I am having difficulties doing the same despite the data being in the same format. I would assume that the query should be the same. Following is my query:

```
SELECT  date_parse(s.pricing_date,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS dataconverted
FROM "mydatabase"."sales" s
```

Following is the error I get in Amazon Athena:

```
Your query has the following error(s):
    [ErrorCategory:USER_ERROR, ErrorCode:INVALID_ARGUMENT], Detail:INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: ""
    This query ran against the "mydatabase" database, unless qualified by the query.
```

How I can convert the successfully convert the variable character text into a date format? What could I possibly be missing?

Comment: can yu please show some examples of date strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it looks like the `pricing_date` column sometimes is an empty string. `date_parse` will throw an error if the input is not on the specified formatat. You can observe this by running `SELECT  date_parse('', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')` or `SELECT  date_parse('asdasd','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')`.

You can work around this by adding a guard (e.g. `IF(s.pricing_date <> '', date_parse(…), NULL)`) or by wrapping the call in `TRY`, which results in `NULL` if there was an error:

```
SELECT try(date_parse(s.pricing_date,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')) AS dataconverted
FROM "mydatabase"."sales" s
```